# product.models.Products.DoesNotExist: Products matching query does not exist

Tags: django

product.models.Products.DoesNotExist: Products matching query does not exist.
i have this problem in my site when i ran this url it show me this error please help in django and this is my
views.py:

```
class GetListProduct(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        products = Products.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)



class Getproduct(APIView):
    def get_object(self, brand):
        comment = Products.objects.get(brand=brand)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(comment)
        return Response(serializer.data)



class Topsellsviews(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        topsellsproduct = TopSells.objects.all()
        serializer = Topsellsserializer(topsellsproduct, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)




class Getdetailproduct(APIView):
    def get(self, request, productid):
        detail = Products.objects.get(productid=productid)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(detail)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and this is my url:

```
from django.urls import path
from.views import GetListProduct, Topsellsviews, Getdetailproduct, Getproduct

urlpatterns = [
    path('product/', GetListProduct.as_view()),
    path('topsells/', Topsellsviews.as_view()),
    path('product/<str:productid>/', Getdetailproduct.as_view()),
    path('product/<str:brand>/', Getproduct.as_view()),
```

when i run /product/productid it worked but when i run /product/brand it not worked

Comment: Can you share the models?

Comment: It seems your Product model has primary key as string type but why ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the order and similarity of URL patterns. Reorder and make them more explicit to resolve the problem.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('product/', GetListProduct.as_view()),
    path('topsells/', Topsellsviews.as_view()),
    path('product/brand/<str:brand>/', Getproduct.as_view()),
    path('product/id/<str:productid>/', Getdetailproduct.as_view()),
]
```